# Why is $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$ rather than $\pm x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value, radicals

Shouldn't the square root of a number have both a negative and positive root? According to Barron's, $\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. I don't understand how.

Comment: Search on this site to find the answer.

Comment: Why should $\sqrt{x^2}=x$? There are two things that square to $x^2$, there is only one thing we call $\sqrt{x}$, you've got to pick one, it may as well be $|x|$.

Comment: By convention, when we write $\sqrt{x}$ for some real, nonnegative $x$, we mean the positive square root.

Comment: Here, we don't know if you mean $\sqrt{x}^2$ or $\sqrt{x^2}$. Use latex. This statement is wrong for the first but right for the other.

Comment: The square root symbol denotes a function. A function has a single value (by convention the positive one is taken).

Answer (score 7):

It is conventional that the notation $\sqrt x$ means the non-negative square root of $x$.

There are indeed two square roots of $x$, and for non-negative numbers $x$, only one of the two is conventionally denoted $\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 2):

Don not confuse $x^2=a^2$ which is an *equation* that has two roots of opposite sign, $\pm\sqrt{a^2}$, and the *expression* $\sqrt{a^2}$, which is a positive number, equal to $|a|$.

Comment: I think it's indeed a good point to distinguish between root function and equation

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common question.  Basically, people like to think, for example, that $\sqrt{9}$ is "the number such that when you square it, you get 9".  So people think this must be $\pm 3$.  But that's not what we are asking with square root.  With $\sqrt{9}$, we are asking for "the **positive** number such that it squared equals $9$".  That means $\sqrt{9} = 3$ (or $\sqrt{3^{2}} = |3|$).

The first (wrong) question applied to the square root should actually be used for solving the equation $x^{2} = 9$.  To solve this, we need to "find the number such that it squared equals $9$", which means the solution is $x = \pm 3$.

Comment: Wow, a downvote and no comment explaining why.  Lazy &@$#!

Answer (score 0):

because even if $x$ is negative $x^2$ is positive, that's why when  you do $\sqrt{x^2}$ you first evaluate $x^2$ which is positive no matter if $x$ is negative or positive. Then you apply the square root which is also positive and so that's why $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ also notice. We evaluated the expression inside out.

$$\sqrt{\color{red}{inside}}$$