# Understanding why If $|a|+1>0$ then $\sqrt{|a|+1}>0$

Tags: calculus

I'm learning calculus and I saw the following statement:

> If $|a|+1>0$ then $\sqrt{|a|+1}>0$. By same logic we get $\sqrt{|b|+1}>0$. Then we get $\sqrt{|a|+1}+\sqrt{|b|+1}>0$.

I don't understand why $\sqrt{|a|+1}>0$. It could be a negative number no? For example if $a=3$ then we get $\sqrt{|3|+1}=\pm2$.

Comment: By convention, when a real number has square roots, $\sqrt{\;\phantom{x}}$ denotes the non-negative root.

Comment: Why? It could have a negative root.

Comment: It's just convention - it's just commonly understood to mean the positive root unless there's a $-$ or $\pm$ in front. There's no deep underlying reason to it, as far as I know.

Comment: It dies have a negative root, but as both roots opposite, the negative root of $a$ is denoted $-\sqrt a$.

Comment: Another duplicate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340738/why-is-sqrtx2-x-rather-than-pm-x)

Comment: This idea is called the principal square root of a nonnegative number: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalSquareRoot.html I can't vouch for this, but I think mathematicians agree that there should be only one square root of a number because we tend to definite operations as functions and a function can't return two output values for a single input value.