# Solving $\frac{\sqrt {x}}{2}=-1$, I get $x=4$. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

We have the equation
$$\frac{\sqrt {x}}{2}=-1$$ I proceed as follows
$$\sqrt {x}=-2 $$
$$x=4$$
Which does not certainly solve the equation. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Whenever you square both sides of an equation, you risk getting solutions to the new equation that don't satisfy the original.
That's just how squaring works...It's an if-then kind of operation, not an only if kind.

Comment: This won't have any solution because there aren't any *real* numbers that can satisfy this equation.

Comment: Even in the set of complex numbers $\Bbb C$, the square root (on the principal branch) is never a negative real: it is either a non-negative real or an element of $\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$, so there isn't any solution in $\Bbb C$ as well.

Comment: @Justin  Where is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: I think you already solved the equation, because square root of any number $n$, has two solutions just as the quadratic $x^2-n=0$, now for which field does the $\sqrt{4}$ represents $-2$ alone

Comment: @Feynstein: Your reasoning isn't flawed. It shows that if there is a solution $x$ to the original equation, it must also satisfy the squared equation giving $x=4$ but $\sqrt 4=2$, hence _no solution exists_ for the original equation, even in $\Bbb C$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Assuming mathematics is a self-consistent field, how can a solution solve one equation, but not the same when represented differently?

Comment: @Feynstein: they are not the same equation: the squared equation introduces extraneous solutions because the map $x\mapsto x^2$ is not injective: for example, consider $x=2$ but its squared equation $x^2=4$ has an extraneous solution $x=-2$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas So I cannot square both sides, while keeping the equation invariant?

Comment: @Feynstein: only the forward implication is true, ie, $f(x)=g(x)\implies f^2(x)=g^2(x)$, not the other way around.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas They never teach us this in school. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Related: [Proving square root of a square is the same as absolute value](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/258876/42969), [Why is $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$ rather than $\pm x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1340738/42969).

Comment: @lonestudent Yeah, I thought in that way. Hence the question.

Comment: Please provide a title that more-accurately conveys the content of your question. Informative titles give you the best chance of attracting answerers; vague and/or generic titles frustrate users searching the site for help on a specific topic. Thanks!

Comment: @Feynstein: If you know that already then why do you write *“And indeed we see that $\sqrt 4 =\pm 2$”* ? – It is still unclear to me what the actual question is. Are you asking why a function cannot take two values for a given argument?

Comment: @MartinR Yes. Absolutely!

Comment: @Feynstein: You may want to look up the definition of a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)): “Intuitively, a function is a process that associates each element of a set X, to a single element of a set Y.”

Comment: @Martin So 4 is a solution if we agree to accept the negative square root as the output for square root function?

Comment: It would have been preferable to **edit** your previous question in order to clarify why the explanations so far were unsatisfactory to you. I think it is possible for you to flag your own question to ask a moderator to merge the two questions together.

Comment: @DavidK Ok flagging to merge. Everybody flag to merge! Also, my previous post got a single answer, after which it was closed. The answer was not satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the square root :

- If $\sqrt x=a$, then

$$\begin{cases} x=a^2 \\ a≥0 \end {cases}$$

Now, you can check your solution.

Note that, $-2$ is the real-valued root of $4$. But, we must take only principal square root, which equals to $2.$

---

Small supplement:

- If $\sqrt x=a$, then you get $x=a^2$. This is correct. But, if the condition $a≥0$ doesn't hold,  then the solution doesn't exist.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120824/discussion-on-answer-by-lone-student-solving-frac-sqrt-x2-1-i-get-x).