# Terminological problem with square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology

I asked [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4059883/409) yesterday, but did not get a satisfactory response.  So let me restate
$$\frac {\sqrt x}{2}=-1$$
$$\implies\sqrt x=-2$$
We can square with the restriction $\sqrt x<0$
$$x=4,\sqrt x<0$$And indeed we see that $\sqrt 4 =\pm 2$ and given the condition $\sqrt x<0$ we get $-2/2=-1$. One possible explanation might be we only take the positive square root, to maintain square root as a function. In this case my question is why cannot square root be a function in this case(when $-ve$ values are included)? Another explanation might be that for $x$ to be a solution, then both positive and negative values must equal $-1$ when divided by $+2$. Is this a issue with terminology?

P.S. The question arose from @eisenstein's comments on [@lonestudent's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4059902/409) to my previous post.

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1618736/42969 (of which your previous question was closed as a duplicate): “Remember $\sqrt x$, when it is defined, denotes the *non-negative* square root of $x$” – So $x=4,\sqrt x<0$ has no solutions in the real number, and $\sqrt 4 = \pm 2$ is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR I know that, and hence I added the terminology tag. But my question is not a duplicate of the aforementioned posts, since I ask more than what those questions ask.