# Tiny doubt with square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a small doubt. Is $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$ true? For, put $x=-1\implies x^2=1$. Now, $\sqrt 1=\pm 1$, whereas $|1|=+1$ only. $x\in\mathbb{R}$

P.S. This doubt came @Daniel's answer from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618732/why-do-i-get-one-extra-wrong-solution-when-solving-2-x-sqrtx?noredirect=1&lq=1) post. To quote-

> The problem appears when you take square roots, since it is not still true that $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=-1$, in fact, $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$ so in this case $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=|-1|=1$, which *is not* equal to $x-2$ when $x=1$.

Comment: What is $x$? An element of $\mathbb{R}$, or?

Comment: Also $\sqrt{1}$ is defined as just $1$ - the square root on real numbers always provides the positive solution to the quadratic equation by definition.

Comment: $\sqrt{1}=\pm 1$ is not quite correct, $\sqrt{1}=1$, because $\sqrt{.}:\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ is defined as the inverse to the restriction $^2:\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$

Comment: Also: [Why is $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$ rather than $\pm x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1340738/42969)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the square root symbol is to indicate the positive square root only, which is why we write $\pm \sqrt{x}$ when we want to indicate both answers. So $\sqrt{1} = 1$ only.

Comment: So my reasoning is not flawed, right?

Comment: You wrote $\sqrt{1} = \pm 1$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Tell me this- $-1^2=+1$? right?

Comment: $(-1)^2 = 1$. However $-1^2 = -1$, because of order of operations, which startled me when I first learned it, as I always thought of "-1" as one thing, rather than "subtracting $1$".  What you wrote says to square $1$, then add a minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your reasoning after the question, therefore I'll state my point without addressing it. The standard notation for the real variable (which is the one used in user Daniel's comment) is that, given $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, $\sqrt\alpha$ is the non-negative real number $u$ such that $u^2=\alpha$, if such a number exist. Therefore the domain of $\sqrt\bullet$ is $[0,\infty)$ and its range is $[0,\infty)$ as well. It follows that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ if $x\in[0,\infty)$ and $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ if $x\in(-\infty,0]$.